# How to remove focus from SearchView?

Tags: android, focus, searchview

I want to remove focus and text from `SearchView` in `onResume()`.

I tried `searchView.clearFocus()` but it is not working.

This is my xml code:

```
<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" />
```

Comment: How is it not working? Causing an error of some sort or just nothing happens? Please be more descriptive...

Comment: show your code buddy :)

Comment: @Vucko actually it is not showing any error and the cursor does not remove.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

> I want to remove focus and text from `SearchView` in `onResume()`

To achieve this you could set your root layout focusable with the `android:focusableInTouchMode` attribute and request focus on that `View` in `onResume()`.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And then in your `Activity`:

```
private View rootView;
private SearchView searchView;

// ...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // ...

    rootView = findViewById(R.id.root_layout);
    searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    searchView.setQuery("", false);
    rootView.requestFocus();
}
```

Comment: If we remove focus (or transfer) from SearchView in onResume, we will see keyboard flashed for a second in some phones. Clearing focus in onPause made it look smoother.

Comment: If you have an adapter, you need to double-check twice. Otherwise, your application may crash.

Answer (score 22):

when in activity go to parent layout  ,and in `fragment` too also do the same thing in `framelayout`. Just add this attribute:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 13):

Use this line of code in your onResume method

```
if (searchView != null) {
    searchView.setQuery("", false);
    searchView.clearFocus();
    searchView.onActionViewCollapsed();
}
```

Comment: it is disabling my focusListner that i don't want, I just want whenever tap on it should come back. and when fragment get load again it should remove.

Comment: Your question was not like this what you have explained now. (I want to remove focus and text from SearchView in onResume() I tried searchView.clearFocus(); but it is not working.)

Answer (score 12):

In your SearchView widget, just add

```
  android:focusable="false"
```

Full widget code

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/your_search_view_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        app:queryHint="Search something..." 
        android:focusable="false" />
```

Comment: hmm, this seems to work just fine. Makes me wonder why all the other answers are more complicated.

Comment: To me, this should be the accepted answer, for the focus part.
Excerpt from documentation about "focusable":
Controls whether a view can take focus.  By default, this is "auto" which lets the framework determine whether a user can move focus to a view.  By setting this attribute to true the view is allowed to take focus. By setting it to "false" the view will not take focus. This value does not impact the behavior of directly calling {@link android.view.View#requestFocus}, which will always request focus regardless of this view.  It only impacts where focus navigation will try to move focus.

Answer (score 3):

Write this code in `onResume()`

```
  searchView.setText("");    
  this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just `searchView.clearFocus();` in `onResume()`helped my case

Answer (score 2):

I had just request focus to some other viewgroup and it removed focus from th searchview. Like in the parent viewgroup eg(Linearlayout, RelativeLayout) in which searchview is present, add

```
focusable = false; focusableInTouchMode=true
```

to the parent viewgroup.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (and I think, the only 100% working) solution is, to create an invisible `LinearLayout`. This `LinearLayout` will grab the focus from the `EditText`.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually hide the keyboard in onResume() function as:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        View view = context.getCurrentFocus();

        if (view == null) {
            view = new View(context);
        }
        if (view != null) {

            IBinder iBinder = view.getWindowToken();

             imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(iBinder, 0);
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking to get rid of the focus when the `Activity` is started *AND* the `SearchView` is in the `Menu`, I did these 3 things, it might work with just a few:

1.- Create a parent class of `SearchView`. Let's call it `RafaSearchView`:

```
class RafaSearchView @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0)
    : SearchView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    init {
        setIconifiedByDefault(false)
    }
}
```

2.- Get the xml where you have your `Toolbar`, and set `touchable="false"` and `focusableInTouchMode="true"`:

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/searchToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

3.- On `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu)` when I'm declaring my `RafaSearchView`, call:

```
    searchView?.isIconified = false
    searchView?.clearFocus()
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work 100% to remove focus from SearchView.

```
override fun onResume() {
    if (searchView != null) {
        searchView.clearFocus();
    }
    super.onResume()
}
```