# Fragment backstack not working when i use searchview with setIconifiedByDefault(false) in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, searchview

My XML contains SearchView and Listview, in Fragment:

```
mSearchView = mView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_sellers_searchView);
mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
```

My Activity:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Fragment fragmentSeller = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("SELLERS");
        if (fragmentSeller != null && fragmentSeller.isVisible()) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        }
    }
```

**issue:** pop back stack not working, when I press back from fragment should go back to the previous fragment, but it's not happening because of,

`mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);`

Comment: is it okay without setIconifiedByDefault ??

Comment: @Md.ibrahim khalil, no its must

Comment: below link solution works for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38411341/how-to-remove-focus-from-searchview

Answer (score 0):

Okay then there’s three possibilities.
First one there may b a mismatch of fragment importation.
Second one you may no be added addtobackstuck on fragment transition. 
And third one is that fragment is closed before entering the if block so fragment is null

Comment: i tested multiple times, its working fine without mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false)